# multi checkbox webpart properties

Tags: 2013, visual-web-part, web-part-property, multi-select

I wish to provide option to Select multiple option in my webpart Properties. Below code only allows me to Select one option. How to Select multiple options?

```
Private colorPicked As MyColors
Public Enum MyColors
Red = 0
Blue = 1
Green = 2
End Enum

<Browsable(True), Category("Select Color"), DefaultValue(""), _WebPartStorage(Storage.Shared), FriendlyName("Color"), _Description("")> _Property BorderStyle() As MyColorsGetReturn colorPickedEnd GetSet(ByVal Value As MyColors)colorPicked = ValueEnd SetEnd Property - See more at: http://www.go4sharepoint.com/Forum/drop-list-web-part-properties-pane-1768.aspx#sthash.twKldCJe.dpuf
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to store a string that serializes all your values.
Obviously, since the string has now a special meaning, `WebBrowsable` only won(t do the magic to translate it into a nice selection UI.
To handle the UI to display/set values in this string, you'll need to develop your own Tool part. You'll find a lot of examples on the Web, e.g.:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584178(v=office.11).aspx
- http://sharepointrenancr.blogspot.fr/2013/04/working-with-toolpart-and-webpart.html

Comment: Is there any full fledge example?

Comment: One I found with my Google-fu: http://microsoftsharepointdevelopment2010.blogspot.fr/2012/03/creating-webpart-with-custom-toolpart.html. It only adds one checkbox, but can be easily extended to multiple checkboxes.

Comment: A good one I've just found, unfortunately (at least for you tavaritch... :-p) it's in French: http://www.developpez.net/forums/d463544/dotnet/general-dotnet/developpement-office-system/sharepoint/moss-toolpart-checkbox-sauvegarde/.  The 4th post in the thread contains a good ToolPart sample that create a CheckBoxList...

Comment: Do i create seperate css file and then i need to refer it?

Comment: CSS? This has nothing to do with CSS... Maybe you mean .cs (C#)? Yup, a ToolPart is made of a dedicated class, so a new .cs file is the recommended approach.

Comment: Oops sorry i meant cs file

Comment: I cant use Visual webpart for this ?

Comment: The ToolPart is not a Web Part. It's a `ToolPart`, a .NET class (**with no designer**). The Web Part it is associated to can be a Visual Web Part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35233/discussion-between-happy-and-evariste).

Comment: I created Visual webpart. Then i added seperate .cs file in my Project. But somehow i am not able to refer webpart in that cs file.. I was following the French link you gave.. I was stuck on this line "ToolPart ParentWp = null;" I think this ToolPart is nothing but webpart.. Am i correct? So in my code i tried EmployeeLinks parentWp = null but i get error

Comment: We could discuss like that forever: explaining everyhting about Web controls/Web Parts/ToolPart is out of the scope of SP.SE. Please, read articles as the ones I mentioned, or look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bATf56gOaqg it has everything you need (if mute your PC!). It is for a sandbox solution (from 3' it's useless for you), but the same goes for a farm solution. Also note he writes the `ToolPart` in the same file as the Web Part (not recommended, but still works).